# Products not visible website

Tags: error, products

After I did bulk status changed like disable all products, after enable all products, after go to see website there is no products display at website.

Comment: try reindexing once if you have less products.

Comment: i did all but no use

Comment: atleast 1 product also not displaying ?

Comment: in my backend 13,000 products are there

Comment: yes, atleast 1 products not displaying

Comment: completely no products display at website

Comment: did you checked status of products in backend under `catalog > manage prodcucts` that products are enabled or disabled ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43793/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-baby-in-magento).